# Why am I getting 'Cannot read property 'length' of null' in this js code?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to integrate this example http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/02/loading-effects-for-grid-items-with-css-animations/comment-page-3/#comments with my own website.

Basically I'm trying to use masonry.js, (which I have working on it's own) with animOnScroll.js to have my images fade in.

```
<script src="AnimOnScroll.js"></script>
    <script>
      new AnimOnScroll( document.getElementById( '.container' ), {
        minDuration : 0.4,
        maxDuration : 0.7,
        viewportFactor : 0.2
      } );
    </script>
```

In Chrome console I am getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of nul      imageLoaded.js
```

And here is the code that is highlighted for the error in imageLoaded.js

```
// turn element or nodeList into an array
function makeArray( obj ) {
  var ary = [];
  if ( isArray( obj ) ) {
    // use object if already an array
    ary = obj;
  } else if ( typeof obj.length === 'number' ) {
    // convert nodeList to array
    for ( var i=0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++ ) {
      ary.push( obj[i] );
    }
  } else {
    // array of single index
    ary.push( obj );
  }
  return ary;
}
```

My css structure is like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid_4"></div>
    <div class="grid_4"></div>
    <div class="grid_4"><div>
</div>
```

Not really sure where to go with this, do I need to change 'number' to the name of my class?  Very lost, any help would be appreciated

Comment: FYI this won't work `document.getElementById( '.container' )` You are referencing a class when it expects an ID

Comment: Carl's comment is likely "the" solution. The `makeArray` function is correct/functional if supplied with *an element* or *Node List* as specified. However, `getElementById('wrong-id')` returns null; which is neither and would cause the error reported.

Comment: I changed it to getElementByClass and now I get "TypeError: undefined is not a function"  with that line highlighted.

Comment: There is no `getElementByClass` function. The error says this. Check the name again.

Comment: You should either give the class an ID as well and reference that using `document.getElementById` or reference the class properly using `document.getElementsByClassName(class)[index]` where `index` is the index of the class in the **DOM** tree

Answer (score 0):

(never mind, I just realized `makeArray` is library code, still leaving this answer for the error explanation)

The problem lies there:

```
if ( typeof obj.length === 'number' )
```

if `obj` is `null`, `obj.length` will raise this exception.

The fix would be:

```
if ( obj && typeof obj.length === 'number' )
```

Comment: This will only bury the error, which is that `obj` is null. Pushing `null` onto the array (such that `[null]` is the result) may make it resurface later. That is, the function is "okay" and the code that calls the function is broken.

Comment: @user2864740 No, it will push `null` to `ary`, assuming that's what the OP intends to do. If it's not the asker's intent, he should add an `if` clause to handle that.

Comment: It is an error surfacing up from the library. The OP is incorrectly supplying `null` as an argument.

Comment: @user2864740 Ok I understand what you mean now. I have no experience with masonry, so I just wanted to explain the error. I think you should post an answer to explain that.